# Unity3d, работа с Translate (столкновения)

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть вот такой код для движения персонажа с помощью свапов. Скрипт лежит в panel (UI).

```
Transform player; // передаю в него объект персонажа

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector2 delta = eventData.delta;

    if (Mathf.Abs(delta.x) > Mathf.Abs(delta.y))
    {
        if (delta.x > 0)
        {
            player.transform.Translate(0.32f, 0, 0);

        }
        else 
        {
            player.transform.Translate(-0.32f, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (delta.y > 0)
        {
            player.transform.Translate(0, 0.32f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            player.transform.Translate(0, -0.32f, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

У меня на карте присутствуют объекты (как вы уже заметили всё размером 32х32 пикселя). Вопрос заключается в следующем, как мне сделать столкновение с ними. Например, если выше него кубик со стеной, то при свопе вверх он оставался не подвижным.

ПыСы Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сверху забыл

public Transform player;

и передаю в него объект персонажа

Comment: Если что-то забыл и нужно дополнить или отредактировать - нажми [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/739601/edit) под вопросом

Comment: Спасибо, учел))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строишь матрицу двухмерную своих кубиков, хранишь индекс ГГ(например **k=5,n=6**, то есть он находится в клетке **[5,6]**). Определяешь куда тебе идти, верх или вниз, влево или вправо. Если влево, то отнимаешь от **k** единицу, если верх, то прибавляешь к **n** единицу(Вообще прибавлять или убавлять, зависит от положения оси координат, я привел пример, если отсчет идет от нижнего левого угла монитора, первая координата это ширина, а вторая высота). Элемент матрицы **[i,j]** может представлять что угодно, информацию что за объект там, псевдовысота и т.д. На основе это информации и делаешь условия проверки, можно ли передвинуться на данную клетку.

Comment: Как я понял, я должен построить матрицу[][] и за счет нее строить из префабов карту. Т.е. у меня карта будет генерироваться кодом. А можно сделать так, чтоб она отображалась до запуска, чтобы я мог на нее посмотреть?

Comment: @dirrm Генерируй ее в editor mode. Погугли execute in edit mode. Либо editor scripts, также scriptableObject полезно будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое